Natural Numbers under Sum Constraints
PROBLEM: Each natural number is coloured blue or red, so if $x$ and $y$ are painted the same colour, then $x+y$ is painted blue (note that it could be $x=y$). Determine all the ways to colour the natural numbers that follow this rule.
MY WORK:
I thought about what happens if I choose a particular number, say $1$, to be blue or red. Suppose I paint $1$ blue. Then, since the sum of $1$ with itself $(1 + 1 = 2)$ must also be blue, it follows that $2$ must be blue. But now I can add $1$ and $2$ to get $3$, which must also be blue, and so on. By repeating this process, I can see that if $1$ is painted blue, then all the numbers obtained by repeatedly adding $1$ must also be blue. This means that all natural numbers will be blue, since every number can be expressed as a sum of ones.
After this I don't know how to continue with the exercise, how can I go on with it, any ideas?

Your problem statement does not make sense.  If $x$ is painted the same color as what?  Please correct it.  It sounds like it should be that if $x$ and $y$ are the same color then $x+y$ is blue.  The next step is to assume $1$ is red and see where that leads.  Is that enough to determine all the numbers or do you find some that are not determined by this.

Corrected, sorry

12 is blue, as 6 + 6. But also 8 + 4. So what is colour of 12?

@EvgeniiEgorov What are your colours for $8$ and $4$? Without spoiling it for the OP (because ROss Milikan's hint is really good!), colour of even numbers are kinda given.

@ThomasAndrews No! What if $1$ and $2$ have separate colours? $3$ is not fixed then.

Show that the set where odd numbers from $1$ to $k$ are red, and all other numbers are blue, satisfy the conditions.  Now, prove that this is all the possibilities.  $\quad$ Hint: Consider the smallest blue odd integer.

Oh, I missed that the same colors always add up to blue.

@CalvinLin Just a little nitpick, the all numbers are blue is also a possibility (already mentioned by the OP, but maybe it could be added to your comment for completeness).

@HackR $k = 0$. $\quad$ Smallest blue odd integer would then be 1.

Hahaha, fair point!
